# yForms multiple language selector not working after publishing on Storefront?

Tags: forms, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on SAP Hybris yForms. We have yForms published with Storefront- electronics (Hybris version 6.5).The yForm created has two languages supported. While testing I can see the language drop-down for selecting language however whenever I publish the form with storefront I am unable to select the language.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: @avernet  Please checkout

Comment: @ebruchez Please Checkout

Comment: I can see the language selector at the top left of the page in your screenshot. By "unable to select the language", are you saying that when you click on it, the list doesn't include the expected languages? Or that nothing shows when you click on it?

Comment: @avernet  Nothing shows when i click on it. That dropdown button is not working. Its like disable. I can't be able to select it.

Comment: Interesting; I don't think that I've ever seen that. Could you try this on other browsers? I.e. if using IE, are you also getting this on Chrome? Also, if getting this on Chrome, with Chrome, can you open the DevTools Console, and see if you have an error message when loading the page or when clicking on the dropdown?

Comment: @avernet yeahh it is really surprising. There is no error on console and in browser. Also i checked with other browsers like IE as you mentioned but nothing works.

Comment: Could you try creating a new form in Form Builder, and in addition to English add a language, say French, and publish the form as-is (so with just 1 field). Does the language picker work in that case? If it does, is the problem happening if add Arabic (instead of French)? Or is everything working in all those cases with a simple form?

Comment: @avernet created new form in form builder added another language french to one of field but still language picker is not working in this case. it is like disabled.

Comment: Got it, thank you for running this test. To make progress on this, I would really need to be able to see the problem, so I can debug it. Do you have this happening on a server that can be accessed publicly, or would you be able to put somewhere a instance that shows this problem and that I can access remotely?

Comment: Akshay, is this still an issue for you? If so, would you be able to deploy this on a publicly accessible server so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @avernet still this issue we are facing.

Comment: Got it, so let's try to figure this out: could you provide answers to the questions in my above comment from Dec 25?

Comment: @avernet yes sure, I will share my screen with you. Let me know your suitable timining. Much needed requirement now. email Id- akshaysnimbalkar@gmail.com

Comment: Got it, let me send you an email about this.